# Airplay works but remote app can’t find AppleTVs

Tags: appletv

I can’t figure out why my Apple TV remote app or built-in control center app for controlling the Apple TV won’t work. It cannot find an Apple TV.

I am on the same network, my iPhone is paired with the Apple TV it shows up in the device list and when I held the close to the Apple TV and offered a chance to pair it. I can also airplay videos and screen mirror to the AppleTV, so it is just something to do with the remote app. Any ideas how to get the remote app to work?

[image: airplay]
[image: remote app]

Comment: Can I confirm if you have bluetooth enabled on both devices? I think that's what you're referring to when you mention that your phone and ATV are paired. Also have you power cycled both devices recently? Which iOS and tvOS are you running? Which iPhone and ATV hardware versions?

Comment: @Scottmeup yes, Bluetooth enabled on both devices. ATV4K latest versions of tvOS and iOS. Power cycled both devices. It’s been happening for quite a while. The weird thing is that AirPlay finds the TVs and can send content to them,but the remote app can’t find them (I have two ATVs on the network)

Comment: Have you removed and re-added the iPhone to the list of remotes on the ATV in tvOS settings?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried all the usual suspects. Deleting the app completely, re-installing. Removing the phone from the list of remotes, trying with different devices (ipads, other iphones). Rebooting the ATV, making sure they were updated.